How to reduce the size of big images only in php?
I have a small php script that loads all images contained in (upload) folder. It also displays them at width 1080 pixels, whatever the image size is. The script works just fine. What I really want to accomplish is trying to shrink only images bigger than 1080 and leaving all smaller images (smaller than 1080) as they are (not resized). I tried to search for a solution but only found complex script with multiplying ratio. I was hoping to get something similar to css tag (max-width="1080") that works in php. But, I think php doesn't have max-width tag.
I tried to implement max-width tag but never worked.
I thank anyone who can modify my code or add something to it to get the proper result. Best regards. Here's my code,
<?php
$files = glob("upload/*.*");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    echo basename($image) . "<br />";
    echo '<img src="' . $image . '" width="1080" alt="Random image" />' . "<br /><br />";
}

?>
But this code below doesn't work.

if($image_width < 1080)
{
    echo basename($image) . "<br />";
    echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="Random image" />' . "<br /><br />";
}

if($image_width > 1080)
{
    echo basename($image) . "<br />";
    echo '<img src="' . $image . '" width="1080" alt="Random image" />' . "<br /><br />";
}
I appreciate if anyone can fix it. Best regards.


You can reduce the image for real with PHP for example with GD or imagick. Doing that in HTML or CSS is no PHP problem.

With your code you limit the display size of the images, but not the image (data) size.

Yes, that's right. I don't need to change the data. I need them for Architectural work. All I need is to display them small. But sometimes I get napkin sketches which are small and when blowing them up they become distorted. The code works fine for large drawings but bad for small prints. I hope I get to modify it to exclude the small images from the code.

I tried to do this, but I get syntax error. I appreciate it if anyone modifies the following code. I am not efficient in php code. Grateful for any help.

What was the problem with max-width? Should be pretty simply to apply that, https://jsfiddle.net/js3fbewz/

You could do this:
<img src="' . $image . '"  alt="Random image" style="max-width:1080px;" />

Thank you sir. It really worked. Such small modification of the code did the trick. It even worked for adjusting to screen width by setting style="max-width:100%;". Thank you again.

Hi, is there a way to display the newest image first? Sorted by time stamp rather than name. Also how to make basename centered with bigger font size. I appreciate any help herein. Thanks.

Every problem has a solution. Just ask a new question so that everyone can
find the right recourse for similar questions. I will be glad to help.
